# linking to an anchor on another page jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a link to an anchor on a jQuery tab, if you know what I mean. I have a page on which I have anchored two tabs, #idTab1 and #idTab2. I use the jQuery idTabs by Sean Catchpole, here... http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/

This is a mocked version of the code I have...

```
<div class="usual">
  <ul class="idTabs">
    <li><a name="idTab1" href="#idTab1" class="selected">Terms of Use</a></li>
    <li><a name="idTab2" href="#idTab2">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>

    <div class="handbook" id="idTab1">
    <p>Some content here...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="handbook" id="idTab2">
    <p>Some content here...</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

What I want to achieve is two links, one for the #idTab1 and the second for #idTab2. I have created the following inside my lower footer...

```
<div class="subfooter">  
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%"><a href="<?php echo url('/content/legal#idTab1');?>">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="<?php echo url('/content/legal#idTab2');?>">Privacy Policy</a><br/>
            <small><?php

            $mtime = explode(' ', microtime());
            $totaltime = $mtime[0] + $mtime[1] - $starttime;
            printf('Page generated in %.3f seconds.', $totaltime);

            ?></small></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The links above actually work, and the page opens, but legal#idTab2 links to the first tab instead. I'd appreciate any tips or help from you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

jquery functions to do it by changing tabs first and going to anchor tab next.

```
<script>
function js_tabs_link(tabnum,anchorLink){
    $('#tabs_container_id').tabs('option', 'selected', tabnum);
    //tabnums start from 1 not 0
    window.location = "#"+anchorLink;
}    
</script>
```

And call the script for your links using

```
<a href='javascript:js_tabs_link("3","about_us")'>about us</a>
```